# use of ようから in this sentence

Tags: grammar

> 噂の広まりようから考えても、飛鳥の意見には同意せざるを得ない。

Even if (i) consider how the rumours spread , (I) can't help but agree with Asuka's comments.

What is the function of ようから, and how does it differ from 噂の広まりようと考えても？

Thank you.

Comment: It is 広まりよう + から.  It is not 広まり + ようから.

Comment: how does it differ from 噂の広まりようと考えても？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`masu-stem + よう` forms a noun phrase, "the way/manner of `verb`", "how something `verb`".

噂の広まりよう**と**考える is incorrect because "the quotative と" marks the content of your thoughts itself. It's equally incorrect to the following sentence in English:

> [×] I think, "The way rumors spread".

Note that "think something" and "think *about* something" is different. In this case, you need to say:

> I think *about* how the rumors spread.

To say something like this, と is not an option. Instead, use the following expressions:

> 噂の広まりよう**を**考えても、…
>   噂の広まりよう**について**考えても、…

These would perfectly fit in your example sentence, too.

～**から**考える is less common, but it means something like "to think based on ～", "to think from ～'s perspective" or "to think with ～ as a starter", depending on the context.